# Request a archivos XML externos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, xml

Trabajo en **NodeJs**, empecé a usar una API para *búsqueda de anime/manga*, pero a diferencia con otras APIs que he utilizado, ésta no estaba disponible en **JSON**, sólo en **XML**.

El formato que tiene es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<anime>
  <entry>
    <id>2889</id>
    <title>Bleach - The DiamondDust Rebellion</title>
    <english>Bleach: Diamond Dust Rebellion</english>
    <synonyms>Bleach: The Diamond Dust Rebellion - M&Aring; 
    Bleach - The DiamondDust Rebellion - Mou Hitotsu no Hyourinmaru</synonyms>
    <episodes>1</episodes>
    <type>Movie</type>
    <status>Finished Airing</status>
    <start_date>2007-12-22</start_date>
    <end_date>2007-12-22</end_date>
    <synopsis>A valuable artifact known as &amp;quot;King's Seal&amp;quot; is stolen...
    Meanwhile, a rogue Hitsugaya searches... (from ANN)</synopsis>
    <image>https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/anime/6/4052.jpg</image>
  </entry>
</anime>
```

¿Cómo debo usarlo y qué variables (o paquetes) debo usar para obtener todos los datos de un archivo como este?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es [xml2js](https://npmjs.com/package/xml2js). Ésta librería te convierte un string xml en un objeto javascript pero en forma de string. Solo necesitas usar `JSON.parse` para tener el xml en objeto.

```
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Puedes ver tu código en funcionamiento con ésta librería [aquí](https://runkit.com/58780dac79a2f60013c1dda4/5878127979a2f60013c1deee).

Otra librería es [xml2json](https://npmjs.com/package/xml2json) que es un parser entre XML y JSON (en ambos sentidos).

```
const parser = require('xml2json');

fetch ('...')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(xml => parser.toJson(xml, { object: true }))
  .then(anime => {
    // hacer algo
  });
```

El parámetro object indica si se desea recibir un `objeto` JavaScript en lugar de un string JSON.

**Nota:** Hay un bug con ésta librería y es que a veces identifica de manera errónea entidades (no suele pasar mucho). Por ejemplo, ésta palabra: `M&Aring` será interpretada como entidad HTML y el parser fallará al intentar convertirla a caracter unicode.

Puedes encontrar más [aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xml).

Comment: ¿Qué es fetch? Estoy probando con este código: `parseString(body, function (err, result) { console.log(result.anime.entry); });` y me devuelve algo parecido a lo siguiente: http://pastebin.com/A2wXnCVt (ahora, ¿cómo obtengo yo los valores del primer `entry`?)

Comment: Es un objeto, `typeof(result.anime.entry)` devolvió `object`. `anime.entry.title` devuelve undefined porque necesito seleccionar uno de los objetos que tiene dentro.

Comment: No importa, solucionado con `result.anime.entry[0].title`.

Comment: En la respuesta te puse un enlace con el codigo funcionando. Solo debías abrir en enlace y mirar el log donde se muestra la estructura del objeto. Saludos.